# NOAA NCEI API Not Receiving Token in Header

Tags: php, libcurl, php-curl

I'm attempting to use [NOAA's weather API](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2#gettingStarted) to retrieve current local weather information for a website.

According to their [documentation](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2#gettingStarted), requests should be in the following format:

```
curl -H "token:<token>" "url"
```

When I execute the above on the command line, replacing `<token>` and `url`, I get a 200 response as expected.

I'm using PHP's cURL library, so I built my request as such (replacing `<token>` with the token I received):

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/locations/',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => 'token:<token>'
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

However, when I execute this request, I get a 400 error with the following message:

```
Token parameter is required.
```

I don't understand how the PHP cURL request is any different from the command line request. How can I change my PHP cURL request to properly send the `token` header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) value need to be an array, not a string:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/locations/',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['token: <token>'] // Use array here
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Without any valid token, the output is :

```
{"status" : "400", "message" : "The token parameter provided is not valid."}
```

Comment: @kittykittybangbang I've tested the exact code of the answer, and it gave me the output _"The token parameter provided is not valid"_.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang Without the array, I got _"Token parameter is required."_.